# inheriting QLPreviewController, changed buttons on navigationItem are being reset after click on "Home"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationitem, qlpreviewcontroller

We have a custom QLPreviewController implementation, so we can control the buttons presented to the user, and their actions.
I have added the following code to the `viewWillAppear` method of the custom class:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(openWithPressed:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPressed:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButtonItem];
    [rightBarButtonItem release];
    [leftBarButtonItem release];
}
```

the previewer does appear with our custom buttons, and they work as expected.
Our problem occurs when the user clicks on the "Home" button. It seams that the `UIApplication.doEvents` method calls the `navigationItem` set button methods, and resets them to the original values (with the original handlers).
How can I prevent this from happening, or handle those events myself, and overwrite them with my own custom buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem. You need to set up a NSNotification that gets called when the application becomes active again, and then reset the navigation bar to how you want it

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(configureNavBar)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
I was using an ugly workaround until now, with a flag, overwriting the nativeItem getter and returning a dummy object so that the OS won't change the real one. I really didn't like it.
Your solution really is much more elegant.